# How to retrieve sites of a specific type using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I'm making an application which connects to SharePoint 2013. I'm using CSOM to work with SharePoint. I want to display the newsfeed of site (Team Site) which the current user follows.

To get the newsfeed, I implement the following step:

- First, I get user's following sites list from `SocialFollowingManager`.
- Next, with the sites information, I get a site's newsfeed information.

When getting followed sites' list (first step above), I can get Blog sites as well as Team Sites. I want to get only Team Sites.

Is there a way to get only Team Site (Team Site Template)?

Comment: It sounds like you already have code - show us code so we know where your problem lies.

Comment: Code is follow as;

ClientContext context = new ClientContext(_siteURL);
SocialFollowingManager followingManager = new SocialFollowingManager(context);
ClientResult<SocialActor[]> followedSiteResult = followingManager.GetFollowed(SocialActorTypes.Sites);
context.ExecuteQuery();

That's code, I can get follow sites.
But I only get following TeamSite information.

Comment: @HidekazuTakahashi The code shall be posted as part of your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Social API only gives you the list of sites.  You'll have to manually filter from there to determine which sites to display.  It's not ideal but it's a limitation in the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientResult<SocialActor[]> socialActors = new SocialFollowingManager(clientContext).GetFollowed(SocialActorTypes.Sites | SocialActorTypes.ExcludeContentWithoutFeeds);
```

That will give you every site excluding those who does not have feeds, ie, TeamSites

Hope it helps!